# Show that a certain type of matrices generate $SL_n(R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-groups

Let $R$  be a commutative ring. Let $E_n (R)$ be the subgroup of $GL_n(R)$ generated by all matrices of the form $I + \lambda$ where $\lambda $ is a matrix with precisely one non zero entry and this entry does not occur on the diagonal. Suppose that $R$ is a euclidean ring. Show that $SL_n(R) = E_n(R)$ (where $SL_n (R) $ are matrices with determinant $1$).

---

I know how to prove this for $R$ is a field, by adding and subtracting some multiple of rows and columns and proceed by induction. But how to do this for a euclidean ring? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to find plenty of proofs of transvections generating SL_n by googling. For example, in here, http://www.pitt.edu/~gmc/algebra/PSL.pdf

Comment: Classical reference: Rotman's book on group theory.

Comment: Both of those references appear only to deal with case when $R$ is a field.

Comment: @user112564: People will be more willing to help if you provide a few thoughts on the problem (where are you stuck?).